# sails waterline sort on number not working(sails-redis)

Tags: sorting, sails.js, waterline, sails-redis

I am trying to do sort id

Modal:

`module.exports = {
     autoPK: false,
     attributes: {
     id: {
         type: 'integer',
         autoIncrement:true,
         primaryKey: true
         },
     }
}`

Query:

```
mymodal.find().sort({id: 'asc'}).exec(function (err, res) {
    console.log(res)
});
```

Data:

[ { id: '2', },{ id: '1'},{ id: '11' } ]

Actual:

[ { id: '1', },{ id: '11'},{ id: '2' } ]

**Expected:

[ { id: '1', },{ id: '2'},{ id: '11' } ]**

Can anybody help me out. Please..

Sorting on string working, but on number(interger).

Is there any with my query or issue with **sails waterline criteria sort**

Comment: when you watch in your database, are you sure if "id" is integer type, your migrate in local.js is equal to "alter"?. you should copy your JSON result, only find().

Comment: Yes.. I am sure in my model id ->      type: 'integer',  autoIncrement: true,  primaryKey: true. Have you tried sorting by id where, id is numeric. using sails-redis. Colud please help me?

Answer (score 1):

First you should do query find and later sort()

```
Modal.find()
.sort({id: 'asc'})
.exec(function(err, res) {
  console.log(res)
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, i have corrected my query on post. Any help

Comment: Need is sails waterline sort by number not by string. Do anybody tried or  faced this issue, any alternative,?

Answer (score 0):

I went through the sails-redis adapter index and schema, few things are missing. while parsing the input data like '11' the method not worried about the data type.
Data like { id: 1 } and { id: '1'} is consider to be different even though in the model

`type: 'integer`

specified.

sails-redis/lib/database/schema.js

changes code:

`Schema.prototype.parse
.
.
  case 'integer':
        values[key] = parseInt(values[key]);
        break;
      case 'float':
        values[key] = parseFloat(values[key]);
        break; 
    }
  }
.
.`

changes working for me. Make sure the values[key] is not null

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/query-language) isn't great on this, but it looks like you might need to use binary notation if you pass an object to `sort()`.  Easier to just pass a string:

```
Model.find().sort('id asc').exec(function (err, res) {
  console.log(res)
});
```